# ES6 errors when bundling (jspm) a React/jsx app

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs, jspm

I'm trying to setup a project using jspm. I've follows [this](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/10/11/react-and-es6-part5.html) great tutorial and it works pretty good, except when I try to bundle

```
$> jspm bundle-sfx app.jsx! app.js --skip-source-maps --minify
Building the single-file sfx bundle for app.jsx!...

err MultipleErrors: cartItem.jsx:5:22: Unexpected token =
      cartItem.jsx:6:21: Unexpected token .
      cartItem.jsx:6:22: Unexpected token PropTypes
      cartItem.jsx:6:31: Unexpected token .
      cartItem.jsx:7:14: Semi-colon expected
      cartItem.jsx:7:14: Unexpected token :
```

([app.jsx](https://github.com/egor-smirnov/egorsmirnov.me-examples/blob/master/react-and-es6-part-5/app.jsx), [cartItem.jsx](https://github.com/egor-smirnov/egorsmirnov.me-examples/blob/master/react-and-es6-part-5/cartItem.jsx), and [github project](https://github.com/egor-smirnov/egorsmirnov.me-examples/tree/master/react-and-es6-part-5))

I get the impression that the bundle tool doesn't understand es6, right?

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, what does the `!` mean following the filename `app.jsx`?

Comment: An author of this post is here :) Thank you! `!` indicates that the loaded file is not JavaScript file, but something else (JSX in that case). That is forced by JSPM itself.

Comment: great post, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have test the following steps and it works fine:

By the way, my jspm version is `0.16.12` by `jspm -v`.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/egor-smirnov/egorsmirnov.me-examples.git
$ cd egorsmirnov.me-examples/react-and-es6-part-5/
$ jspm init
$ jspm install
$ jspm bundle-sfx app.jsx! app.js --skip-source-maps --minify
```

Comment: I've done the steps again, and now I can't reproduce it anymore, so I guess something was messed up before somehow. Thnx a lot!

Comment: I can reproduce it again. Now every time I run that command I get the errors. I'm using jspm version 0.16.27 and node v0.10.40 (and 5.3.0). I've also tried to use 0.17.0-beta6 but then I get a `no such file or directory, open '/home/dev/workspace/tmp/egorsmirnov.me-examples/react-and-es6-part-5/babel'`